# IE7 float on new line

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

My application uses some bars on a timeline. Every line consists of a barkeeper div that holds the bars for this line. The barkeeper also has 2 style properties width and height.

```
.barkeeper {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    position: relative;
}
```

The bars have some interactive ajax actions that come from Richfaces and CSS hover and jquery javascript. Therefore around each bar there is a form. I've left out the action javascript to simplify this example.

```
.bar {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 0;
}

<form id="j_id163:0:j_id165:0:medfrm" onmouseover="" method="post" name="j_id163:0:j_id165:0:medfrm" target="">
    <div id="bar1" class="bar antibiotic" onmouseout="" onmouseover="" style="left: 7px; width:1528px;">
        <img style="float:right;" src="endarrow.gif">
        <div class="cornr_top">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center; direction: ltr;">Bartext </div>
        <div class="cornr_bottom">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    </div>
   <input type="hidden" value="" name="" autocomplete="off">
   <input type="hidden" value="" name="autoScroll" autocomplete="off">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   <input id="javax.faces.ViewState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="" name="javax.faces.ViewState">
</form>
```

The bars are absolutaly positioned using a left and width parameter.

The bars have to have rounded corners so  I've added these cornr_top and cornr_bottom

```
.cornr_top div, .cornr_top, .cornr_bottom div, .cornr_bottom {
    font-size: 1px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}

.cornr_top {
    background: url("../img/tr.gif") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
}

.cornr_top div {
    background: url("../img/tl.gif") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
}
```

The cornr_bottom classes are identicaly defined except for the images being used.

The last thing I've added is this line

```
<img style="float:right;" src="endarrow.gif">
```

This displays a running an arrow at the end of the bar to indicate that it is still running.

Now every browser displays all of this correctly. The corners are added to the corners and if available the arrow overrides the right side of the bar and overlaps the 2 corners over there.

[image: Arrow in firefox]
[image: No arrow in firefox]

In IE7 the arrow is displayed on a new line. How can I resolve this issue?

[image: Arrow in IE7]
[image: No arrow in IE7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution myself.

I've changed the arrow image tag from

```
<img style="float:right;" src="endarrow.gif">
```

to

```
<img style="position:absolute; right:0px;" src="endarrow.gif">
```